# Getting jQuery Cycle plugin issue transparant image black border and white background in IE

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-cycle

## **[Demo link](http://www.2cbdesign.com/demo/test/SideModule.htm)**

Hi,

I am getting black border and white background issue inside IE for transparent images when I user jQuery Cycle plugin.

So I know this is known issue but I am not able to figure this out.

this is what i tried so far :

1. unitpngfix.js did not do the trick
2. cleartype: false (did make paragraph transparent but made the image border black)
3. background-color: transparant (did make paragraph transparent but made the image border black)

Is there anything I am missing here ?

This is only happening in IE.

Thanks,

## update

I have updated the code...now i dont get white background because I made the div height zero how ever my slide show is laging in between..its really slow in IE when it changes the image from 1 to another and it is also not smooth.

Comment: I have only been able to get opacity animation on transparent png's working if I use unitpngfix, the png is the CSS background-image property of a child element and I animate the opacity on the parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could not find the answer to this. Looks like if text and images are user together, they do not have smooth effect. I have updated my question and provided the answer. Try increasing speed and time property.